# how to know what files or folder are changed before do commit

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

My problem is how to know what files or folder are changed before do commit. I can add all the new files in my working copy before do commit, and the repository changes, but if for example i delete one file of the working copy i dont know the way to add this change before do commit. When you use the tortoise for example before do commit the program shows all the changes of the working copy and you can choose what changes commit and what changes dont. There is some way to do this usin sharp svn?? thanks for your answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
svn status
```

will tell you the state of the working copy compared to where it was before your last update/commit, if you want to delete something in svn use `svn delete`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, could you show me an example of using these functions? I dont understand the operation of status parameters

Comment: EventHandler < SvnStatusEventArgs > statusHandler = new EventHandler<SvnStatusEventArgs>(void(object, SvnStatusEventArgs) target);
client.Status(path, statusHandler);

Comment: is this of use to you pedro?
http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=728&dsMessageId=301985